# Which is the radius of convergence of the complex power series?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

We have the function $$f(z)=\exp \left (\frac{(e^{6z}-1-6z)^2}{z\sin \left (\frac{z}{4}\right )\left (1-\cos \left (\frac{2z}{5}\right )\right )}\right )$$ Which is the radius of convergence of the powerseries $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(6i)}{n!}(z-4\pi i)^n}$ ?

Let $a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(6i)}{n!}$. Then in this case we ue the ratio test, or not?

We have $$\left |\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right |=\left |\frac{\frac{f^{(n)}(6i)}{n!}}{\frac{f^{(n+1)}(6i)}{(n+1)!}}\right |=\left |\frac{f^{(n)}(6i)}{f^{(n+1)}(6i)}\right |\cdot (n+1)$$ So we have to check the derivative of the function $f$, right? So we have to find a general formula of the $n$-th derivative, or is there an other way?

Comment: Hint: Recall $\sum \frac{1}{n!}f^{(n)}(z_0)(z-z_1)^n$ is $f(z-(z_1-z_0))$ and the radius of convergence is the distance to the nearest singularity of $f$.

Comment: The singularity is where $z\sin (z/4)(1-\cos (2z/5))$ is zero? @user10354138

Comment: Be careful!  Removable singularity doesn't count.

Comment: We have to write the exponential i the numerator as a function of sine and cosine? @user10354138